# Disable SaveAs in Word

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I need to either disable SaveAs in word or prevent the User from changing the file name.

My application allows the user to create a MailMerge Document using headers I provider for them. This works when the user just simply Saves and exits Word. If the user Saves As, the application locks up.

I'm using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`.

```
 //MyWordApp & doc is initialized.

 MyWordApp.Application.Visible = true;

 While(WordIsOpen())//Holds execution here while User is editing in Word
 {
 }
```

WordIsOpen Definition:

```
 public bool WordIsOpen()
 {
       if (MyWordApp.Application.Visible)//Locks up here
       {
           return true;
       }
       else
           return false;
 }
```

Lock up:

```
 //I have a BeforeSave event that Saves the doc and quits Word

 DocumentBeforeSave(Doc, SaveAsUI, Cancel)
 {
      //Save Doc

      MyWordApp.Quit(ref objFalse, ref objNull, ref objNull);//Also, Locks up here
 }
```

Comment: Why not fix it so that the application doesn't lock up?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to determine why the application locks up and fix that?

Comment: i've tried fixing it. I've changed the way i've been doing it. Gone full circle and ended back at the method you see here.

Comment: Do you close the doc before quitting the application?

Comment: I wasn't. Just tried it and it throws a `The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)` exception on the `doc.close()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what ultimately caused this issue. I determined it has something to do with the COM behavior. There is a known bug while using the Word Interop in debug mode. The only way I came across that could potentially resolve this issue is to intercept COM events occurring before or on SaveAs. I did not implement that solution so I do not know what is all involved in that.